# Controlling UISwitch in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` and a class for the cell. I then load this cell in my viewController into a tableview. The custom cell has a label and a UiSwitch. I have managed to get the switch to work as I want it to and change values that are needed to change.

I now wanted a separate UISwitch outside of the `UITableView` - that when it is turned on - all the switches in the UITableView are turned on.

For some reason i cannot get this to work.

This is the code for the custom cell:

```
- (void)selectAllSwitches:(BOOL)selected 
{
    if (selected){
        [self.selectSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self.selectSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

}
-(void)setMaillist:(BBMailList *)aMaillist
{
    maillist = aMaillist;

    if (maillist){
        self.nameLabel.text = maillist.name;

        if (self.maillist.isSubscribed){
            self.selectSwitch.on = YES;
        }else{
            self.selectSwitch.on = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)switchControl:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    self.maillist.isSubscribed = !self.maillist.isSubscribed;

    NSLog (@"IsSubScribed: %ul", self.maillist.isSubscribed);

    if (self.maillist.isSubscribed){
        self.selectSwitch.on = YES;
    }else{
        self.selectSwitch.on = NO;
    }
}
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
static NSString *mailListTableViewCellIdentifier = @"BBMailListTableViewCell";

if (tableView == self.maillistTableview ){

    BBMailListTableViewCell * maillistTableviewCell = [self.maillistTableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mailListTableViewCellIdentifier];
    if (!maillistTableviewCell){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:mailListTableViewCellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        maillistTableviewCell = nib[0];
    }


    if ([self.mailLists count ] > 0){
        NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.mailLists];
        [newArray removeLastObject];
        [newArray removeLastObject];
        [self.maillistTableview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];

        BBMailList *maillist = newArray[indexPath.row];

        maillistTableviewCell.maillist = maillist;
    }

    return maillistTableviewCell;
}
```

This code works as I need it to.

I then created an IBAction methon in my viewController for the UISwitch that is outside of the tableView

```
- (IBAction)selectAllSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    BBMailListTableViewCell *switchButton = [[BBMailListTableViewCell alloc]init];
    [switchButton selectAllSwitches:YES];
}
```

This runs the correct method in my UITableViewCell class - but the UITableView doesn't reflect the changes. I added `[self.myTableView reloadData];` - but this did not solve the issue. Can anyone shed some light not his for me?

****UPDATE****

Updated Code for the UISwitch outside of the UITableView

```
- (IBAction)selectAllSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{

    BBMailList *tempMailList = [[BBMailList alloc]init];

    tempMailList.isSubscribed = YES; 

    [self.maillistTableViewCell setMaillist:tempMailList];

    [self.maillistTableViewCell selectAllSwitches:YES];


    [self.maillistTableview reloadData];


}
```

Each mailistItem is a NSObject I use to store data with. The above code runs the correct methods - but it seems I am not keeping the state maybe and when [self.mayTableView reloadData]; runs - it resets the tableview data to original state?

Comment: I didn't see call to - (IBAction)selectAllSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender method anywhere in table view's delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: in the action method `- (IBAction)selectAllSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender` u are creating the new cell this will not at all related or connected to your tableview how u think it will change the state of all the cell in tableview

Comment: @Allamaprabhu - That's because I don't want to set all the switches with a switch inside the tableview. The selectAll switch is outside of table view. Shan I have corrected that to use the same instance as the tableviewcell that is loaded in the tableview - still no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic to solve the problem would be:

1) From your code it looks that the on/off functionality is dependent on your `maillist.isSubscribed` property. In your `IBAction` of viewcontroller, set it to `true`.

2) Call `[self.myTableView reloadData];` in this IBAction. So once the table loads cell the array's element will help the switch set to ON/OFF.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

It seems like you are losing your track. Because in your IBAction of your viewController you are creating a new array of type `BBMailList`. Try like this:

Assuming your `self.mailLists` is a collection of `BBMailList` type.

Now:

```
- (IBAction)selectAllSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    // loop through each array element set it to true.
    for (BBMailList *tempMailList in self.mailLists)
    {
        tempMailList.isSubscribed = Yes;
    }

    // reload table data so once table
    [self.maillistTableview reloadData];
}
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` change your setting up of mail list like this:

```
if ([self.mailLists count ] > 0){
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.mailLists];
    [newArray removeLastObject];
    [newArray removeLastObject];
    [self.maillistTableview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];

    BBMailList *maillist = newArray[indexPath.row];

    [maillistTableviewCell setMaillist: maillist]; // <--- Changed this line
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and it hasn't solved the issue. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: This answer lead me to the solution. I had to keep the selected state of the switch in my cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. Everything working as I need it to now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add `UISwitch` to all cells and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` **hide** `UISwitch` in cell you dont want to display it.

**You need to add:** 

1)Array for state(on/off switch state) 

2)Array for state(hide/unhide switch)on cells

Then change state's array as your application logic 
and when you will reload `UITableView` data it should display data as per state's array values
e.g.

arrayHideUnhide = (@"YES",@"NO",@"YES",@"NO");

arrayOnOff = (@"ON","OFF",@"ON");

Comment: I don't want to hide the switches.

Comment: @Tander - Oh that's great - then only one array needs to be maintained