# UISearchBar with table view and checkbox tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uisearchbar

Can anyone suggest a tutorial which can achieve following 3 tasks for one ViewController.

```
1. Search names in tableView.
2. Each cell in tableView has checkBoxes.
3. Retain checked cells [state of `UIButtons`] if the user searches the name.
```

So far I have achieved first two tasks from this [lengthly code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694309/retain-uitableview-cell-state-when-uisearchbar-is-used) 
but unable to achieve 3rd point. Any help will be sincerely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How can you expect a Tutorial according too your requirements and that to for customization features.

Comment: its not that I did not try anything. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694309/retain-uitableview-cell-state-when-uisearchbar-is-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You can't expect tutorials to do exactly what you are doing.

There are many ways of doing this. One of the ways is to store the state of the checked cells in an `NSArray` and then load the state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method.

Comment: i did that. Please refer 'boolDict' which is NSMutableDictionary in cellForRowAtIndexPath from this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694309/retain-uitableview-cell-state-when-uisearchbar-is-used

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue with the following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //static NSString *cellId = @"CheckBoxedCell";
    NSString *cellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    CheckBoxedCellClass *cell = (CheckBoxedCellClass *)[self.tableViewContact dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *nib;
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckBoxedCellClass" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckBoxedCellClass_iPad" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        for (id object in nib)
        {
            if([object isKindOfClass:[CheckBoxedCellClass class]])
            {
                cell = (CheckBoxedCellClass *)object;
                break;
            }
        }

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    //set fonts
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {

        [cell.companyLabel setFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:10.0]];
    }
    else
    {

        [cell.companyLabel setFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
    }

    //handling check box

    NSInteger rowNumber = 0;
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section ; i++)
    {
        rowNumber += [self tableView:self.tableViewContact numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    }

    rowNumber += indexPath.row;

    SaveCheckBoxedView *saveContact;
    if(isFiltered == YES)
    {
        saveContact = [filterdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = saveContact.nameString;
        cell.companyLabel.text = saveContact.companyString;
    }
    else
    {
        saveContact = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nameLabel.text = [[objectsForCharacters objectForKey:[arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.companyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [companyArray objectAtIndex:rowNumber]];
    }

    cell.invIdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", saveContact.invitId];

    UIButton *checkBox;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        checkBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 8, 30, 30)];
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 13, 30, 30)];
    }



    [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    // handle check box view reset when scrolled



    if(isFiltered == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"filtered");
        BOOL buttonPress = [[boolDictForSearch objectForKey:[filteredArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"button press = %d", buttonPress);
        [checkBox setSelected:buttonPress];
        if(buttonPress)
        {
            [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        checkBox.tag = indexPath.row;
    }
    else
    {
        BOOL buttonPressed = [[boolDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowNumber]] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"button pressED = %d", buttonPressed);
        NSLog(@"Row number = %d", rowNumber);
        [checkBox setSelected:buttonPressed];


        if(buttonPressed)
        {
            [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        checkBox.tag = rowNumber;
    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];

    return cell;
}


-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableViewContact];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewContact indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"value of indexPath.section %d ,indexPath.row %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"Tag number = %d", [sender tag]);


    if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]])
    {
        [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checkBoxMarked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSUserDefaults *buttonDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [buttonDefault setBool:YES forKey:@"CHECKMARKEDKEY"];


        [self.boolDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]]];
        //[self.boolDictForSearch setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", saveContact.nameString]];

        if(isFiltered == YES)
        {
            NSString *addId = [filteredArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [self.boolDictForSearch setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:addId];

            NSLog(@"filterd id = %@", addId); //get filtered array here
            [arrayOfIds addObject:addId];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *finalIntId = [mutableArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag];

            [self.boolDictForSearch setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:finalIntId];

            NSLog(@"Tagged checked button id = %@", finalIntId);
            [arrayOfIds addObject:finalIntId];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"UnChecked");

        [self.boolDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]]];
        //[self.boolDictForSearch setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", saveContact.nameString]];

        if(isFiltered == YES)
        {
            [arrayOfIds removeObjectIdenticalTo:[filteredArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag]];
            [self.boolDictForSearch setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:[filteredArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag]];
        }
        else
        {
            [arrayOfIds removeObjectIdenticalTo:[mutableArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag]];
            [self.boolDictForSearch setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:[mutableArrayOfIds objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ಠ_ಠ That is exactly my solution.

Comment: guys I have followed this guide and everything worked, I only problem ... when I select a check in normal mode, when I go into search mode (using UISearchBar) the previous check is not more 'displayed as unchecked returns ... 

Where am I doing wrong?